# Erro no python dizendo que o arquivo não existe, mas ele existe

Tags: python

Código:

```
import csv
import random

dataset = []

with open('data.csv') as _file:
    data = csv.reader(_file,delimiter=',')
    for line in data:
        line = [float(elemento) for elemento in line]
        dataset.append(line)
```

Erro:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'
> ```

Arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O script que você executa é esse `Rn.py` ?

Comment: sim, os dois estão na mesma pasta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que você está executando o seu arquivo python uma pasta antes de `RD2`, o que acaba definindo a raíz do projeto como a pasta que contém a pasta `RD2`. (Creio que está executando pelo VSCode)

Então quando você usa o `with open('data.csv')`, ele procura o arquivo na raíz. E, como ele realmente não existe nessa pasta, ele irá dar o erro.

Se você jogar o `data.csv` fora de `RD2`, a execução ocorrerá normalmente.
Ou você coloca `with open('RD2/data.csv') as _file:` que também irá funcionar! :)

Comment: obrigado, agora esta funcionando

Comment: De nada, @BrunoLuizBender :)

Comment: Se possível, marcar a resposta como solução para que outras pessoas vejam que a pergunta já foi respondida :)